# Inspect module if contains funcs/coros/methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, inspect

I have a directory, like this:

```
my_directory/
|
├── sub_dir/
|   ├── bar.py
|   └── foo.py
|
├── sub_dir_b/
|   └── file4.txt
|
├── sub_dir_c/
|   ├── config.py
|   └── my_test_file.py
|
├── file1.py
├── file2.py
└── file3.txt
```

Now I want to check every function and method of each python-file, if the expected return value is a Coroutine type.

Question: Is there a way to inspect these files (by there absolute path)?

In `my_test_file.py` I have a function, which returns the abspath of my Pythonfiles (via os.walk), but it seems like this won't help me any further at the moment.
Do I have to import them as a module anyhow, because then there may be a solution with `inspect.getmembers()` or is there a better way without importing them?

I know that I can check a return value type by getting the functions/methods `__annotations__` like:

```
async def bar(j):
    return None

def foo(i:int,j:int)-> Coroutine:
    res = i+j
    return bar

foo.__annotations__["return"]
```

Will return: `typing.Coroutine` which I can compare to.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to check? The return type of a function is generally not knowable without running the function and inspecting the return value; even then there is no guarantee that the return type is stable wrt input or history.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I have functions in a more complex directory and some functions normally shall be a Coroutine and await the result of these. But (many) functions just return the Coroutineobject which is wrong. Theses Objects shall return the awaited result and so the functions should be "async def". So I thought checking all return valuetypes would have been the way.

Comment: First, please note there is nothing wrong with a function returning a coroutine; an ``async def`` is just syntactic sugar for a function returning a coroutine. In the end, you have to ``await`` the result of the function call either way. Second, it is still not clear to me *how* you want to find out which functions match. Are all functions annotated? If so, what makes you think they are wrong? If they are not annotated, what is your criteria to find out?

Comment: I guess I was barking up the wrong tree. @medo mentioned the same point in the answer below. I hoped I could get informations about the return value-type over this "arrow Operator" (I don't know the specific name) via foo.__annottations__ and than say "this thing shall normally await a Coroutine, not returning a Coroutine itself". But I neither can promise if every function is annotated, nor if a returned Coroutine may be right, nor if the real return valuetype will be a Coroutine either. So I will have to check everything manually or try to test everything until it breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Should do the trick, not sure what you need this for really, since in python nothing forces you to return the annotated type, but hey, was fun solving this.

```py
from importlib import import_module
from inspect import getmembers, isfunction
from pathlib import Path

modules = {}
for f in Path('.').rglob('*.py'):
    if f.as_posix() != __file__:
        module = '.'.join(f.parts[:-1]+('',)) + f.stem
        modules[f.stem] = import_module(module)

for members in map(getmembers, modules.values()):
    for member in members:
        name, function = member
        if isfunction(function):
            return_type = function.__annotations__.get('return', None)
            print(name, return_type)
```

Comment: I have never worked with this "arrow Operator" before and thought this would make some trouble if the return type is not as the expected one. =/ I wanted to find functions, which return Coroutineobjects atm. These Coroutineobjects should be awaited and so the function itself should have been "async def". So I wanted a list of all these "faulty" functions.

Comment: `modules[f.stem] = import_module(module)` seems to break if relative imports are existent. `ImportError: attemted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: Interesting, I tried it on the exact directory tree you posted and it worked for me. Do you have anything different in your setup?

Comment: But if I understand you correctly, you're trying to find faulty code. I doubt any linters would fit your use case, but if the directory you're working with is small; the best way would be to find all cases manually. And what if you forgot to annotate a function or did so wrongly, how would you find those anyway? Type annotations are here like an appendix to documentation. They don't serve as function declarations that you have in other programming languages.

Comment: The functions are not faulty, because returning a Coroutineobject is legit (and so the linter doesn't care about them as well). But it break, if I expected something else ( like "foo was not awaited" or similar error messages). But well, I think I have to accept my destiny to either write a test which calls everything anyhow or look it up manually or wait until everything breaks (*yikes*)

Comment: yep, you can solve it with tests,  'assert' statements might help you with debugging.